# How to use contours to detect rectangles with 1 uneven side?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

This is the rectangle:

[image]

The reason I want to detect this is because I am trying to detect traffic light box in images. And when I look at the edge diagram for some of the images than the lower edge of the traffic light might be distorted or uneven which fails my contour algorithm to detect the box.

traffic light:

[image]

Comment: What is your final goal? If to detect the light, then you can detect it directly. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html

Comment: I am required by my class assignment to find the box first, than find the color of the circle

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can find contour of the object no matter how its shape is. In your case, I find the biggest contour (green) and then get the bounding rectangle (red) of it.

```
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i,c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    #remove small contours and too big contours
    if area > 500 and area < 30000:
        rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.drawContours(img, contours, i ,(0,255,0), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(img,(rect[0],rect[1]),(rect[0]+rect[2],rect[1]+rect[3]),(0,0,255),2)
```

[image]

But I think in real-life scenarios, you'll never get a trafic light with such high resolution like that, so it could be more complicated to find them. I recommend to use some preprocessing techniques such as sobelx, threshold, morphologyEx, ... before extracting contours. And you also need to find suitable conditions such as ratio check, area check,... to filter those contours to get the right trafic light.